# matplotlib: is a changing background color possible?

Tags: python, background, matplotlib, plot

matplotlib python:
How do you change the background color of a line plot according to a given column?
Say I have the following data file

```
1. 0
4. 0
2. 0
1. 1
2. 1
3. 1
3. 2
1. 2
2. 2
```

The first column represents the y-values, and the 2nd column should control the background color. Say, it plots the (black) line on a white-gray alternating background (zebra-like) as proceeding further in x-direction, where the transition in color occurs anytime the integer in the 2nd column increments. Or other possible solution: Use 2nd column as function argument to determine background color.

How would one do this with matlibplot?

Comment: You might want to ask specific questions like this on matplotlib's user mailing list.

Comment: I guess you use this example as a starting point.[span_regions](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/span_regions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works:

```
    plt.axvspan(x, x2, facecolor='g', alpha=0.5)
```

where facecolor is the foreground color